# Redirecting STDERR and STDOUT to a log file when script is executed via php

Tags: php, exec

I have a scenario where a php file runs a perl script file using exec function. I want STDOUT and STDERR to be redirected to a log file which can then be read via ajax call to another php file.

Problem: I'm unable to redirect STDOUT and STDERR when the script is called via PHP.

Php code:

```
$cmd=getcwd().'/scheduledscrape.pl --path='.$spath.' --size='.$filesize;
$outputlastline = exec($cmd, $output);
print $outputlastline;
```

I tried to modify the above existing code by changing it to:

```
$cmd=getcwd().'/scheduledscrape.pl --path='.$spath.' --size='.$filesize.' >log.txt 2>&1';
```

but nothing happened. Reading about this on the php documentation, it was commented that to redirect the output, one needs to invoke another shell script. Hence I tried this:

```
$cmd=getcwd().'/runscript.sh '.getcwd().'/scheduledscrape.pl --path='.$spath.' --size='.$filesize;
$outputlastline = exec($cmd, $output);
print $outputlastline;
```

and the shell script contained:

```
echo "$@" > running.txt
"$@" >log.txt 2>&1
```

But again nothing happened, i.e the perl script runs but the log file isnt getting created. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does the user you're running PHP as have permissions to create files in that directory? You can also redirect the output streams directly to PHP if you use [`proc_open()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php).

Comment: yes. I tested with `sudo -u wwwuser touch file`. I'm using f_open in the other file.